# ImportError with Google Text-to-Speech(gTTs)

Tags: python-3, text-to-speech

I am getting an error when trying to import gTTs for python 3.8. I have to use 3.8 for my project I am working on. `

I entered in `from gtts import gTTs`

when I do this I receive an erro saying:
ImportError: cannot import name 'gTTs' from 'gtts' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtts/**init**.py)

What am I doing wrong?

I am using [Adafruit mini speaker](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3369?gclid=Cj0KCQjwvYSEBhDjARIsAJMn0lha6G8XNvzuehjcUs1HDqmoFCAdYotu-WAl_cykpt3eVmdGI2Rw_x0aAh2dEALw_wcB)

I am running Raspbian Stretch v 9 and I have a RPi 3 B+

Comment: it's not `gTTs` ... please review the example code

Comment: [gTTs-PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/) This is where I got this from. Can you explain further what you mean by "it's not gTTs"

Comment: `This is where I got this from` ... read that page again

Comment: Can you directly tell me what the problem is? I would like an answer to the post and not innuendos

Comment: I'm trying to help you to solve it on your own ... it's `gTTS`, not `gTTs` .... all you had to do was to read the example code on that page

Comment: @jsotola I'm so dense, apologies for the misunderstanding! A lot going on, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your import statement.

It should be `from gtts import gTTS` with an uppercase S at the end.

(Also Kudos for providing as much info as possible in your question :) )